# Получение данных socket tcp / udp

Tags: c#, сокет, websocket, tcp

Нужно получить пакет данных на публичный IP и вернуть сообщение.

Код ниже обрабатывает только локальные запросы 192.168.0.0:1100.
При отправке данных на публичный IP (Например, через telnet) приложение ничего не видит.

Брандмауэр отключен полностью (общий, частный и профиль домена - отключено все).

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace SocketTcpServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static int port = 1100; // порт для приема входящих запросов
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IPEndPoint ipPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);

            Socket listenSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            try
            {
                listenSocket.Bind(ipPoint);
                listenSocket.Listen(10);
                Console.WriteLine("Сервер запущен. Ожидание подключений...");
                while (true)
                {
                    Socket handler = listenSocket.Accept();
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    int bytes = 0;
                    byte[] data = new byte[256];
                    do
                    {
                        bytes = handler.Receive(data);
                        builder.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
                    }
                    while (handler.Available > 0);
                    Console.WriteLine(builder);

                    data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("message");
                    handler.Send(data);
                    handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    handler.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);}
        }
    }
}
```

**UPD:** Использую STUN для того, чтобы "пробить" порт

```
STUN = STUN_Client.Query(StunServer, StunServerPort, socket);
Console.WriteLine("Public address: {0}", STUN.PublicEndPoint);
```

Получаю публичный IP и порт автоматически, но **пакеты все равно не доходят**
Для проверки использую linux команды: echo “hello” > /dev/udp/ip/port и ping

Comment: Компьютер на котором работает приложение находится за роутером?

Comment: Расскажите подробнее, что такое внешний IP? У вас роутер с NAT? Делали проброс порта?

Comment: Устройство за роутером. Другие приложения, например торрент на 6881 порту,  прекрасно раздают пакеты данных. **Приложение должно запускаться** и после получения прав от брандмауэра получать пакеты, **без дополнительных настроек**

Comment: `Другие приложения, например торрент на 6881 порту, прекрасно раздают пакеты данных.` Они скорее всего через UPnP открывают себе порт. Можете погуглить как через UPnP открывать порты в C#.

Comment: UPnP может быть отключен на роутере, использую STUN для открытия порта, но все без толку